# Get file path from app.setting and not hard coded in my class

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

How I can get file path from app.setting to my class. For example, I hard codded the file path on my class like

> var x= $"{Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)}\mydoc.docx";

But I want to get it from app.setting like

> "PluginSettings": {
> "mypath": ["path to my desktop"
>
> ],
> "mytemplate": ["path to my desktop"]
> },

so I want my class get the mypath anmytemplate from app.setting.
any help

Comment: You can search for IOptions pattern and dependency injection. Assuming you are using net core or later.

Comment: I used  string dbConn2 = configuration.GetSection("PluginSettings").GetSection("templateDocxFilePath").Value; and get error Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' Im using .net6 console application.

Comment: I went to different approach  This is my appsetting "RoundTheCodeSync": {
    "Title": "Our Sync Tool",
    "Interval": "0:30:00",
    "ConcurrentThreads": 10
  },    and I code like       var x = _configuration.GetSection("RoundTheCodeSync").GetChildren().FirstOrDefault(config => config.Key == "Title").Value;    and still get  error Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Answer (score 0):

You have a bug in your code. GetChildren creates a list of your properties, so you have to find a proper items  using where at first. But since it will return a list of items that fits a where condition, you will have to select a first item and after this a value, a path or a key of this item

```
var title = configuration.GetSection("RoundTheCodeSync")
                         .GetChildren()
                         .FirstOrDefault(c =>c.Key=="Title" )
                         .Value;
```

but there is a much shorter way, since a section just is a dictionary

```
 var title = configuration.GetSection("RoundTheCodeSync")["Title"];
```

Comment: still have same error.

Comment: public Program(IConfiguration config)
        {
            _config = config;
        }        var applicationSettings =  _config.GetSection("RoundTheCodeSync");  and still have same error

Answer (score -1):

I figure out the simple solution

> var appname = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build().GetSection("RoundTheCodeSync")["Title"];

And it's work fine.